# "Real Function is Strictly Concave iff Derivative is Strictly Decreasing" - doubt about a step in the proof

Tags: real-analysis

On [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Function_is_Strictly_Concave_iff_Derivative_is_Strictly_Decreasing), we have this:

[image]

---

My doubt is about whether the conclusion "$f'(x_1)>f'(x_4)$" is justified and whether the strict inequality should not be replaced by a weak one.

I have this doubt because I thought that if $a_n>b_n$ for all $n$, then we can only conclude that $\lim a_n\geq \lim b_n$.

Am I mistaken? If so, why? If not, how can we fix the above proof?

Comment: It's certainly true that $a_n>b_n$ for all $n$ only implies $\lim a_n \geq \lim b_n$. Take $2/n$ and $1/n$ as examples.

Comment: The proof given is wrong. when you take limits $>$  becomes $\geq $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof itself is indeed wrong, because strict inequalities become weak when taking the limits. However it is not hard to fix : simply don't ignore the middle term.

Consider the first part $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} > \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2} $ and let $x_2 \to x_1^+$, then the inequality becomes 
$f'(x_1) \geq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1}$. Here I just want to rename the argument to get that $f'(x_1) \geq \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$, and this is true for all $x_2>x_1$

Similarly, using the other side, we can prove that for all $x_3<x_4$, we have $\frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}\geq f'(x_4)$.

Now by strict concavity, if $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$, then we have $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} > \frac{f(x_4) - f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}$, and by the two previous steps, $f'(x_1)\geq \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} > \frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}\geq f'(x_4)$

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the proof lacks a bit of justification; however, we can give a justification that makes this proof work.

If we have a number $x_{1.5}$ with $x_1 < x_{1.5} < x_2$, then we claim that
$$
\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_{1.5})}{x_2 - x_{1.5}} > \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_{1})}{x_2 - x_{1}}.
$$
For suppose that this were false; then
$$
\frac{f(x_{1.5}) - f(x_1)}{x_{1.5} - x_1} < \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_{1.5})}{x_2 - x_{1.5}} \leq \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_{1})}{x_2 - x_{1}}
$$
Abbreviate this as $\alpha < \beta \leq \gamma$. Then we also have $(x_{1.5} - x_1)\alpha + (x_2 - x_{1.5}) \beta < (x_2 - x_1) \gamma$, but writing that out, it means that
$$
f(x_2) - f(x_1) < f(x_2) - f(x_1).
$$
Thus our claim holds. It follow that the limit you take (in the original argument) on the left hand side is of an increasing sequence, while the limit you take on the right hand side is of a decreasing sequence. Hence the inequality is strict.

**Edit:** A cleaner way to do essentially the same thing is to introduce 5 points instead of 4: we have $x_1, \ldots, x_5$. Then the inequality becomes
$$
\dfrac {f \left({x_2}\right) - f \left({x_1}\right)} {x_2 - x_1} > \dfrac {f \left({x_3}\right) - f \left({x_2}\right)} {x_3 - x_2} > \dfrac {f \left({x_4}\right) - f \left({x_3}\right)} {x_4 - x_3}> \dfrac {f \left({x_5}\right) - f \left({x_4}\right)} {x_5 - x_4},
$$
and letting $x_2 \to x_1^+$ and $x_4 \to x_5^{-}$ shows an inequality $f'(x_1) > f'(x_5)$ with a strict gap.